# convert ascii to netcdf format using r language

Tags: r

I have data in .asc format, given below.

```
ncols          241  
nrows          291  
xllcenter    91.33  
yllcenter     5.00  
cellsize       0.1  
NODATA_value  -999   

133.0 136.0 138.0 141.0 144.0 147.0 150.0 152.0 155.0 157.0 159.0 162.0 164.0 167.0 159.0 147.0 135.0 123.0 111.0 98.0 86.0 84.0 81.0 79.0 76.0 74.0 71.0 70.0 70.0 70.0 71.0 71.0 72.0 72.0 84.0 101.0 118.0 134.0 151.0 168.0 185.0 197.0 209.0 222.0 234.0 246.0 258.0 266.0 266.0 266.0 266.0 265.0 265.0 265.0 254.0 237.0 221.0 204.0 188.0 171.0 155.0 156.0 158.0 160.0 161.0 163.0 164.0 165.0 162.0 159.0 156.0 153.0 150.0 147.0 144.0 140.0 137.0 133.0 130.0 126.0 123.0 120.0 117.0 114.0 111.0 108.0 105.0 102.0 99.0 97.0 94.0 92.0 89.0 86.0 85.0 84.0 83.0 82.0 81.0 80.0 79.0 78.0 77.0 76.0 75.0 73.0 72.0 71.0 70.0 70.0 69.0 68.0 67.0 67.0 66.0 65.0 64.0 63.0 62.0 61.0 60.0 59.0 58.0 57.0 56.0 55.0 54.0 53.0 52.0 51.0 51.0 50.0 49.0 48.0 47.0 46.0 45.0 45.0 44.0 43.0 42.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 37.0 35.0 34.0 33.0 32.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 28.0 27.0 27.0 26.0 26.0 25.0 25.0 24.0 24.0 23.0 22.0 21.0 21.0 20.0 19.0 19.0 18.0 17.0 16.0 15.0 15.0 14.0 13.0 12.0 11.0 11.0 10.0 9.0 9.0 8.0 7.0 7.0 6.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 7.0 7.0 8.0 8.0 9.0 9.0 10.0 10.0 10.0 10.0 11.0 11.0 12.0 12.0 13.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 15.0 
133.0 137.0 140.0 143.0 146.0 149.0 153.0 155.0 158.0 160.0 162.0 164.0 166.0 168.0 161.0 148.0 135.0 123.0 110.0 97.0 85.0 83.0 81.0 78.0 76.0 74.0 72.0 71.0 72.0 72.0 73.0 74.0 74.0 75.0 86.0 103.0 120.0 137.0 154.0 171.0 188.0 199.0 210.0 220.0 231.0 242.0 252.0 259.0 259.0 259.0 258.0 258.0 258.0 257.0 247.0 231.0 215.0 199.0 184.0 168.0 152.0 155.0 158.0 161.0 164.0 167.0 169.0 170.0 166.0 162.0 158.0 154.0 150.0 145.0 142.0 138.0 134.0 130.0 126.0 122.0 118.0 115.0 112.0 110.0 107.0 104.0 101.0 98.0 96.0 93.0 91.0 88.0 86.0 83.0 82.0 81.0 80.0 79.0 78.0 77.0 75.0 74.0 73.0 72.0 71.0 70.0 69.0 68.0 67.0 67.0 66.0 65.0 65.0 64.0 63.0 63.0 62.0 61.0 60.0 59.0 59.0 58.0 57.0 56.0 55.0 54.0 53.0 52.0 52.0 51.0 50.0 49.0 48.0 48.0 47.0 46.0 45.0 44.0 43.0 42.0 42.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 37.0 35.0 34.0 33.0 32.0 31.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 28.0 27.0 27.0 26.0 26.0 25.0 24.0 24.0 23.0 23.0 22.0 21.0 21.0 20.0 19.0 18.0 17.0 17.0 16.0 15.0 14.0 13.0 13.0 12.0 11.0 10.0 10.0 9.0 8.0 8.0 7.0 7.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 7.0 7.0 8.0 8.0 8.0 9.0 9.0 10.0 10.0 11.0 11.0 12.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 14.0 15.0 16.0 16.0 
134.0 138.0 141.0 145.0 148.0 152.0 156.0 159.0 161.0 162.0 164.0 166.0 168.0 170.0 162.0 149.0 136.0 123.0 110.0 96.0 83.0 82.0 80.0 78.0 77.0 75.0 73.0 72.0 73.0 74.0 75.0 76.0 77.0 78.0 89.0 106.0 123.0 140.0 157.0 174.0 191.0 200.0 210.0 219.0 228.0 238.0 247.0 253.0 252.0 252.0 251.0 251.0 250.0 250.0 240.0 225.0 210.0 194.0 179.0 164.0 149.0 153.0 158.0 162.0 166.0 170.0 174.0 176.0 170.0 165.0 160.0 154.0 149.0 144.0 139.0 135.0 131.0 126.0 122.0 118.0 114.0 111.0 108.0 105.0 102.0 100.0 97.0 94.0 92.0 90.0 87.0 85.0 83.0 81.0 79.0 78.0 77.0 75.0 74.0 73.0 72.0 71.0 70.0 69.0 68.0 66.0 65.0 65.0 64.0 64.0 63.0 63.0 62.0 62.0 61.0 61.0 60.0 59.0 59.0 58.0 57.0 57.0 56.0 55.0 54.0 53.0 52.0 52.0 51.0 50.0 49.0 49.0 48.0 47.0 46.0 46.0 45.0 44.0 43.0 42.0 41.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 37.0 35.0 34.0 33.0 32.0 32.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 29.0 28.0 27.0 27.0 26.0 25.0 25.0 24.0 24.0 23.0 22.0 22.0 21.0 20.0 20.0 19.0 18.0 17.0 16.0 16.0 15.0 14.0 13.0          12.0 12.0 11.0 10.0 9.0 9.0 8.0 7.0 7.0 6.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 7.0 7.0 8.0 8.0 9.0 9.0 10.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 14.0 15.0 16.0 17.0 17.0 
135.0 139.0 143.0 147.0 151.0 155.0 159.0 162.0 163.0 165.0 167.0 169.0 170.0 172.0 164.0 150.0 136.0 123.0 109.0 95.0 82.0 81.0 79.0 78.0 77.0 76.0 74.0 74.0 75.0 76.0 77.0 78.0 79.0 80.0 92.0 109.0 126.0 143.0 160.0 177.0 194.0 202.0 210.0 218.0 226.0 233.0 241.0 246.0 246.0 245.0 244.0 244.0 243.0 242.0 232.0 218.0 204.0 190.0 175.0 161.0 147.0 152.0 158.0 163.0 169.0 174.0 180.0 181.0 175.0 168.0 162.0 155.0 149.0 142.0 137.0 132.0 128.0 123.0 118.0 114.0 109.0 106.0 104.0 101.0 98.0 96.0 93.0 90.0 88.0 86.0 84.0 82.0 80.0 78.0 76.0 75.0 73.0 72.0 71.0 69.0 68.0 67.0 66.0 65.0 64.0 63.0 62.0 61.0 61.0 61.0 60.0 60.0 60.0 59.0 59.0 59.0 58.0 58.0 57.0 57.0 56.0 55.0 55.0 54.0 53.0 53.0 52.0 51.0 50.0 50.0 49.0 48.0 47.0 47.0 46.0 45.0 44.0 44.0 43.0 42.0 41.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 37.0 36.0 34.0 33.0 33.0 32.0 31.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 29.0 28.0 27.0 27.0 26.0 25.0 25.0 24.0 23.0 23.0 22.0 21.0 21.0 20.0 19.0 18.0 18.0 17.0 16.0 15.0 14.0 14.0 13.0 12.0 11.0 10.0 10.0 9.0 8.0 8.0 7.0 7.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 7.0 7.0 8.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0 17.0 18.0 18.0 
135.0 140.0 144.0 148.0 153.0 157.0 161.0 165.0 166.0 168.0 169.0 171.0 172.0 174.0 165.0 151.0 137.0 123.0 109.0 94.0 80.0 80.0 79.0 78.0 77.0 76.0 76.0 75.0 77.0 78.0 79.0 80.0 82.0 83.0 95.0 112.0 129.0 146.0 163.0 180.0 197.0 204.0 210.0 216.0 223.0 229.0 236.0 240.0 239.0 238.0 237.0 236.0 235.0 235.0 225.0 212.0 198.0 185.0 171.0 157.0 144.0 151.0 157.0 164.0 171.0 178.0 185.0 186.0 179.0 171.0 163.0 156.0 148.0 140.0 134.0 129.0 124.0 120.0 115.0 110.0 105.0 102.0 99.0 97.0 94.0 92.0 89.0 87.0 85.0 83.0 81.0 79.0 77.0 75.0 73.0 72.0 70.0 69.0 67.0 66.0 65.0 64.0 63.0 62.0 61.0 59.0 58.0 58.0 58.0 58.0 57.0 57.0 57.0 57.0 57.0 56.0 56.0 56.0 56.0 55.0 55.0 54.0 54.0 53.0 52.0 52.0 51.0 51.0 50.0 49.0 48.0 48.0 47.0 46.0 45.0 45.0 44.0 43.0 43.0 42.0 41.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 37.0 36.0 35.0 34.0 33.0 32.0 32.0 31.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 29.0 28.0 27.0 26.0 26.0 25.0 24.0 24.0 23.0 22.0 22.0 21.0 21.0 20.0 19.0 18.0 17.0 17.0 16.0 15.0 14.0 13.0 13.0 12.0 11.0 10.0 9.0 9.0 8.0 8.0 7.0 6.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 7.0 7.0 8.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0 17.0 18.0 19.0 19.0 
136.0 141.0 145.0 150.0 155.0 160.0 164.0 168.0 169.0 171.0 172.0 173.0 175.0 176.0 167.0 152.0 137.0 123.0 108.0 94.0 79.0 79.0 78.0 78.0 77.0 77.0 77.0 77.0 78.0 80.0 81.0 83.0 84.0 86.0 97.0 115.0 132.0 149.0 166.0 183.0 200.0 205.0 210.0 215.0 220.0 225.0 230.0 233.0 232.0 231.0 230.0 229.0 228.0 227.0 218.0 205.0 192.0 180.0 167.0 154.0 141.0 149.0 157.0 165.0 173.0 181.0 190.0 192.0 183.0 174.0 165.0 156.0 148.0 139.0 132.0 127.0 121.0 116.0 111.0 105.0 100.0 97.0 95.0 93.0 90.0 88.0 85.0 83.0 81.0 79.0 77.0 75.0 74.0 72.0 70.0 69.0 67.0 66.0 64.0 62.0 61.0 60.0 59.0 58.0 57.0 56.0 55.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 55.0 55.0 55.0 55.0 55.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 53.0 53.0 52.0 52.0 51.0 51.0 50.0 49.0 48.0 48.0 47.0 46.0 46.0 45.0 44.0 44.0 43.0 42.0 42.0 41.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 37.0 36.0 35.0 34.0 33.0 33.0 32.0 32.0 31.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 28.0 28.0 27.0 26.0 25.0 25.0 24.0 23.0 23.0 22.0 22.0 21.0 20.0 19.0 19.0 18.0 17.0 16.0 15.0 15.0 14.0 13.0 12.0 11.0 11.0 10.0 9.0 9.0 8.0 7.0 7.0 6.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 7.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0 17.0 18.0 19.0 19.0 20.0 
136.0 140.0 145.0 150.0 154.0 159.0 164.0 167.0 168.0 170.0 171.0 172.0 173.0 174.0 165.0 150.0 135.0 121.0 106.0 91.0 77.0 76.0 76.0 76.0 76.0 76.0 76.0 76.0 77.0 79.0 80.0 82.0 83.0 84.0 97.0 114.0 132.0 149.0 167.0 184.0 202.0 207.0 213.0 218.0 224.0 229.0 235.0 238.0 236.0 233.0 231.0 229.0 227.0 225.0 218.0 210.0 201.0 193.0 184.0 176.0 167.0 172.0 177.0 182.0 187.0 192.0 197.0 197.0 188.0 179.0 171.0 162.0 153.0 144.0 136.0 130.0 123.0 117.0 110.0 104.0 97.0 95.0 92.0 90.0 87.0 85.0 82.0 80.0 78.0 77.0 75.0 73.0 71.0 70.0 68.0 67.0 65.0 64.0 63.0 61.0 60.0 59.0 58.0 57.0 57.0 56.0 55.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 51.0 51.0 50.0 50.0 49.0 48.0 48.0 47.0 47.0 46.0 45.0 45.0 44.0 43.0 43.0 42.0 42.0 41.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 37.0 36.0 35.0 34.0 34.0 33.0 33.0 32.0 32.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 28.0 28.0 27.0 26.0 25.0 25.0 24.0 24.0 23.0 22.0 22.0 21.0 20.0 19.0 18.0 18.0 17.0 16.0 15.0 14.0 13.0 13.0 12.0 11.0 10.0 10.0 9.0 8.0 8.0 7.0 6.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 7.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0 17.0 18.0 19.0 20.0 
136.0 140.0 145.0 149.0 154.0 158.0 163.0 166.0 167.0 169.0 170.0 171.0 172.0 173.0 163.0 148.0 134.0 119.0 104.0 89.0 74.0 74.0 74.0 74.0 74.0 74.0 75.0 75.0 76.0 78.0 79.0 81.0 82.0 83.0 96.0 114.0 132.0 149.0 167.0 185.0 203.0 209.0 215.0 221.0 227.0 233.0 240.0 243.0 239.0 236.0 233.0 229.0 226.0 223.0 219.0 215.0 210.0 206.0 202.0 198.0 194.0 195.0 197.0 199.0 201.0 203.0 204.0 203.0 194.0 185.0 176.0 167.0 158.0 149.0 141.0 133.0 125.0 117.0 110.0 102.0 94.0 92.0 89.0 87.0 84.0 82.0 79.0 77.0 76.0 74.0 72.0 71.0 69.0 67.0 66.0 65.0 64.0 63.0 61.0 60.0 59.0 58.0 58.0 57.0 56.0 55.0 55.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 50.0 50.0 49.0 49.0 48.0 48.0 47.0 47.0 46.0 46.0 45.0 45.0 44.0 43.0 43.0 42.0 41.0 41.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 37.0 36.0 36.0 35.0 34.0 34.0 33.0 32.0 32.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 29.0 28.0 27.0 26.0 26.0 25.0 24.0 24.0 23.0 22.0 22.0 21.0 20.0 19.0 18.0 17.0 16.0 15.0 15.0 14.0 13.0 12.0 11.0 11.0 10.0 9.0 9.0 8.0 7.0 7.0 6.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0 17.0 18.0 19.0 
135.0 140.0 144.0 149.0 153.0 158.0 162.0 166.0 166.0 167.0 168.0 169.0 170.0 171.0 162.0 147.0 132.0 117.0 102.0 87.0 72.0 72.0 72.0 73.0 73.0 73.0 74.0 74.0 76.0 77.0 78.0 80.0 81.0 82.0 95.0 113.0 131.0 150.0 168.0 186.0 204.0 211.0 218.0 224.0 231.0 238.0 244.0 247.0 243.0 238.0 234.0 229.0 225.0 220.0 219.0 219.0 219.0 219.0 220.0 220.0 220.0 219.0 217.0 216.0 215.0 213.0 212.0 208.0 199.0 190.0 181.0 172.0 163.0 154.0 145.0 136.0 127.0 118.0 109.0 100.0 91.0 89.0 86.0 84.0 81.0 79.0 77.0 74.0 73.0 71.0 70.0 68.0 67.0 65.0 64.0 63.0 62.0 61.0 60.0 59.0 58.0 58.0 57.0 56.0 56.0 55.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 50.0 50.0 50.0 49.0 49.0 49.0 48.0 48.0 48.0 47.0 47.0 46.0 46.0 45.0 45.0 44.0 44.0 43.0 42.0 41.0 41.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 38.0 37.0 36.0 35.0 35.0 34.0 33.0 33.0 32.0 31.0 30.0 30.0 29.0 28.0 27.0 27.0 26.0 25.0 25.0 24.0 23.0 22.0 21.0 20.0 19.0 19.0 18.0 17.0 16.0 15.0 14.0 13.0 13.0 12.0 11.0 10.0 10.0 9.0 8.0 7.0 7.0 6.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0 17.0 18.0 19.0 
135.0 140.0 144.0 148.0 153.0 157.0 161.0 165.0 166.0 166.0 167.0 168.0 169.0 170.0 160.0 145.0 130.0 115.0 100.0 84.0 69.0 70.0 70.0 71.0 71.0 72.0 73.0 73.0 75.0 76.0 77.0 79.0 80.0 81.0 94.0 113.0 131.0 150.0 169.0 187.0 206.0 213.0 220.0 228.0 235.0 242.0 249.0 252.0 246.0 241.0 235.0 229.0 224.0 218.0 219.0 224.0 228.0 233.0 237.0 242.0 246.0 242.0 237.0 233.0 228.0 224.0 219.0 213.0 204.0 195.0 186.0 177.0 168.0 159.0 150.0 139.0 129.0 119.0 109.0 98.0 88.0 86.0 83.0 81.0 79.0 76.0 74.0 72.0 70.0 69.0 67.0 66.0 65.0 63.0 62.0 61.0 61.0 60.0 59.0 58.0 57.0 57.0 56.0 56.0 55.0 55.0 54.0 54.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 50.0 50.0 50.0 50.0 50.0 49.0 49.0 49.0 49.0 48.0 48.0 48.0 47.0 47.0 47.0 46.0 46.0 45.0 45.0 44.0 44.0 43.0 42.0 42.0 41.0 40.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 37.0 37.0 36.0 35.0 34.0 33.0 33.0 32.0 31.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 28.0 28.0 27.0 26.0 25.0 25.0 24.0 23.0 22.0 21.0 20.0 19.0 18.0 17.0 16.0 16.0 15.0 14.0 13.0 12.0 11.0 11.0 10.0 9.0 8.0 8.0 7.0 7.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0 17.0 18.0 
135.0 139.0 144.0 148.0 152.0 156.0 161.0 164.0 165.0 165.0 166.0 167.0 168.0 168.0 158.0 143.0 128.0 113.0 97.0 82.0 67.0 68.0 68.0 69.0 70.0 71.0 71.0 72.0 74.0 75.0 76.0 78.0 79.0 80.0 93.0 112.0 131.0 150.0 169.0 188.0 207.0 215.0 223.0 231.0 238.0 246.0 254.0 257.0 250.0 243.0 236.0 230.0 223.0 216.0 220.0 228.0 237.0 246.0 255.0 264.0 272.0 265.0 257.0 250.0 242.0 234.0 227.0 219.0 210.0 201.0 192.0 183.0 174.0 165.0 154.0 142.0 131.0 120.0 108.0 97.0 85.0 83.0 80.0 78.0 76.0 73.0 71.0 69.0 68.0 66.0 65.0 64.0 62.0 61.0 60.0 60.0 59.0 58.0 58.0 57.0 56.0 56.0 56.0 55.0 55.0 54.0 54.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 50.0 50.0 50.0 49.0 49.0 49.0 49.0 49.0 49.0 49.0 49.0 48.0 48.0 48.0 48.0 48.0 48.0 47.0 47.0 46.0 46.0 45.0 45.0 44.0 44.0 43.0 43.0 42.0 41.0 41.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 38.0 37.0 36.0 35.0 34.0 34.0 33.0 32.0 32.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 29.0 28.0 27.0 26.0 25.0 25.0 24.0 23.0 22.0 21.0 20.0 19.0 18.0 17.0 16.0 15.0 14.0 13.0 12.0 12.0 11.0 10.0 10.0 9.0 8.0 7.0 7.0 6.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 17.0 18.0 
135.0 139.0 143.0 148.0 152.0 156.0 160.0 163.0 164.0 164.0 165.0 165.0 166.0 167.0 157.0 142.0 127.0 112.0 97.0 82.0 67.0 68.0 69.0 69.0 70.0 71.0 72.0 73.0 74.0 75.0 76.0 78.0 79.0 80.0 93.0 111.0 129.0 147.0 165.0 184.0 202.0 212.0 223.0 234.0 244.0 255.0 266.0 272.0 269.0 266.0 263.0 260.0 257.0 255.0 257.0 261.0 265.0 269.0 274.0 278.0 282.0 273.0 264.0 255.0 246.0 237.0 228.0 219.0 213.0 206.0 199.0 193.0 186.0 180.0 169.0 156.0 143.0 130.0 117.0 104.0 91.0 88.0 85.0 82.0 78.0 75.0 72.0 70.0 68.0 67.0 66.0 64.0 63.0 62.0 61.0 60.0 59.0 59.0 58.0 57.0 56.0 56.0 56.0 55.0 55.0 55.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 50.0 50.0 50.0 50.0 50.0 50.0 50.0 50.0 50.0 49.0 49.0 49.0 49.0 48.0 48.0 47.0 47.0 46.0 46.0 45.0 45.0 44.0 43.0 43.0 42.0 41.0 41.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 37.0 36.0 36.0 35.0 34.0 33.0 33.0 32.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 29.0 28.0 27.0 26.0 25.0 24.0 23.0 22.0 21.0 20.0 19.0 18.0 17.0 16.0 16.0 15.0 14.0 13.0 12.0 11.0 11.0 10.0 9.0 8.0 8.0 7.0 7.0 6.0 6.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 15.0 16.0 
135.0 139.0 143.0 147.0 151.0 155.0 159.0 162.0 162.0 163.0 164.0 164.0 165.0 165.0 156.0 141.0 126.0 111.0 97.0 82.0 67.0 68.0 69.0 69.0 70.0 71.0 72.0 73.0 74.0 75.0 77.0 78.0 79.0 80.0 92.0 110.0 127.0 144.0 162.0 179.0 196.0 210.0 223.0 237.0 250.0 264.0 277.0 286.0 288.0 289.0 290.0 291.0 292.0 293.0 294.0 293.0 293.0 293.0 293.0 292.0 292.0 281.0 271.0 260.0 250.0 239.0 229.0 220.0 216.0 212.0 207.0 203.0 199.0 194.0 183.0 169.0 154.0 140.0 126.0 111.0 97.0 93.0 89.0 85.0 81.0 77.0 74.0 71.0 69.0 68.0 66.0 65.0 64.0 62.0 61.0 60.0 60.0 59.0 58.0 57.0 57.0 56.0 56.0 56.0 55.0 55.0 55.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 51.0 50.0 50.0 49.0 49.0 49.0 48.0 48.0 47.0 46.0 46.0 45.0 44.0 44.0 43.0 42.0 41.0 40.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 37.0 36.0 35.0 35.0 34.0 33.0 32.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 28.0 27.0 27.0 26.0 25.0 24.0 23.0 22.0 21.0 20.0 19.0 18.0 17.0 16.0 15.0 14.0 13.0 13.0 12.0 11.0 10.0 10.0 9.0 8.0 8.0 7.0 6.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 11.0 12.0 13.0 14.0 
135.0 139.0 143.0 147.0 151.0 154.0 158.0 161.0 161.0 162.0 162.0 163.0 163.0 164.0 154.0 140.0 125.0 111.0 96.0 82.0 67.0 68.0 69.0 70.0 70.0 71.0 72.0 73.0 74.0 75.0 77.0 78.0 79.0 80.0 92.0 108.0 125.0 141.0 158.0 174.0 191.0 207.0 223.0 240.0 256.0 272.0 289.0 301.0 306.0 311.0 317.0 322.0 327.0 332.0 331.0 326.0 321.0 316.0 311.0 307.0 302.0 290.0 278.0 266.0 254.0 242.0 230.0 221.0 219.0 217.0 215.0 213.0 211.0 209.0 198.0 182.0 166.0 150.0 134.0 118.0 102.0 98.0 93.0 89.0 84.0 80.0 75.0 71.0 70.0 69.0 67.0 66.0 64.0 63.0 62.0 61.0 60.0 59.0 58.0 57.0 57.0 56.0 56.0 56.0 56.0 55.0 55.0 55.0 55.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 53.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 52.0 51.0 51.0 50.0 50.0 49.0 48.0 48.0 47.0 46.0 46.0 45.0 44.0 43.0 43.0 42.0 41.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 37.0 37.0 36.0 35.0 34.0 33.0 32.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 28.0 27.0 26.0 25.0 24.0 23.0 22.0 21.0 20.0 19.0 18.0 17.0 16.0 16.0 15.0 14.0 13.0 12.0 12.0 11.0 10.0 9.0 9.0 8.0 7.0 7.0 6.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 7.0 8.0 9.0 9.0 10.0 11.0 11.0 12.0 
136.0 139.0 143.0 146.0 150.0 154.0 157.0 160.0 160.0 161.0 161.0 162.0 162.0 162.0 153.0 139.0 124.0 110.0 96.0 82.0 67.0 68.0 69.0 70.0 71.0 71.0 72.0 73.0 74.0 76.0 77.0 78.0 79.0 80.0 91.0 107.0 123.0 138.0 154.0 170.0 185.0 204.0 224.0 243.0 262.0 281.0 300.0 316.0 325.0 334.0 343.0 352.0 362.0 371.0 368.0 358.0 349.0 340.0 330.0 321.0 312.0 298.0 285.0 271.0 258.0 244.0 231.0 222.0 222.0 223.0 223.0 224.0 224.0 224.0 213.0 195.0 178.0 160.0 143.0 126.0 108.0 103.0 98.0 92.0 87.0 82.0 76.0 72.0 71.0 69.0 68.0 66.0 65.0 63.0 62.0 61.0 60.0 59.0 58.0 58.0 57.0 56.0 56.0 56.0 56.0 56.0 55.0 55.0 55.0 55.0 55.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 54.0 53.0 53.0 52.0 52.0 51.0 51.0 50.0 49.0 49.0 48.0 47.0 47.0 46.0 45.0 44.0 43.0 42.0 41.0 41.0 40.0 39.0 38.0 37.0 36.0 35.0 34.0 33.0 32.0 31.0 30.0 29.0 28.0 27.0 26.0 25.0 24.0 23.0 22.0 20.0 20.0 19.0 18.0 17.0 16.0 15.0 14.0 14.0 13.0 12.0 11.0 10.0 10.0 9.0 8.0 8.0 7.0 7.0 6.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 4.0 4.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 4.0 4.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 7.0 7.0 8.0 8.0 9.0 10.0 10.0 
136.0 139.0 143.0 146.0 150.0 153.0 157.0 159.0 159.0 160.0 160.0 160.0 160.0 161.0 152.0 138.0 123.0 109.0 95.0 81.0 67.0 68.0 69.0 70.0 71.0 72.0 73.0 73.0 75.0 76.0 77.0 78.0 79.0 80.0 91.0 105.0 120.0 135.0 150.0 165.0 180.0 202.0 224.0 246
```

Now I want to convert into NetCDF file. I imported the .asc file using

`asc = import.asc("/Users/Pushp/Desktop/test/CF/2004/Eta-20040101-India-RH50.asc")`

then change into raster

`raster = raster(asc)`

Now I want to change this raster file into NetCDF file?

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
library(raster)
asc <- raster("Eta-20040101-India-RH50.asc")
x <- writeRaster(asc, "eta.nc")
```